# Orleans single threaded nature not respected by ContinueWith

Tags: c#, asp.net, actor, orleans

I have the following code (https://github.com/avinash0161/OrleansExperiments/tree/c0155b4b0c8c1bfe60aea8624f2cc83a52853dc7):

```
// Client code
Console.WriteLine("Client making a call");
var hashGenerator = client.GetGrain<IGrainA>(0);
hashGenerator.Call_A_ToTemp();
await Task.Delay(1000);
hashGenerator.Call_B_ToTemp();

// GrainA code
public async Task Call_A_ToTemp()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Making call A to a fellow grain");
   IGrainB grain = this.GrainFactory.GetGrain<IGrainB>(1);

   grain.CallA().ContinueWith((t)=>
   {
     if(t.IsFaulted)
     {
       // Silo message timeout is 32s so t.IsFaulted is true
       Console.WriteLine("Task Faulted");
       Call_A_ToTemp();
     }
    });
}

public async Task Call_B_ToTemp()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Making call B to a fellow grain");
   IGrainB grain = this.GrainFactory.GetGrain<IGrainB>(1);
   await grain.CallB();
}

// GrainB code
public async Task CallA()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Call A came to GrainB");
   await Task.Delay(34000);  // more than timeout for the caller
}

public Task CallB()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Call B came to GrainB");
   return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

The output for this code is:

```
Client making a call
Making call A to a fellow grain
Call A came to GrainB
Making call B to a fellow grain
Task Faulted                       <---------------- This comes after Call_B_ToTemp executes
Making call A to a fellow grain
```

As we can see, that Call_B_ToTemp executes before Call_A_ToTemp executes completely (ContinueWith part of Call_A_ToTemp is executed later). Is this expected and does it violate the single threaded nature of the grains?

---

When I replaced the code in Call_A_ToTemp() with:

```
public async Task Call_A_ToTemp()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Making call A to a fellow grain");
    IGrainB grain = this.GrainFactory.GetGrain<IGrainB>(1);

    bool isSuccess = false;
    while (! isSuccess)
    {
       try
       {
          await grain.CallA();
          isSuccess = true;
       } catch(TimeoutException){
            Console.WriteLine("task faulted");
       }

    }
}
```

The code now preserves the single threaded nature and Call_B_ToTemp isn't called till all of `ContinueWith` part of Call_A_ToTemp() is executed. The console output is like:

```
Client making a call
Making call A to a fellow grain
Call A came to GrainB
Task Faulted                       
Making call A to a fellow grain
```

Can anyone please explain this? Is the single threaded nature violated when there is `ContinueWith`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The single-threaded nature is not being violated. The compilation warnings in your project makes the source of the issue clear. In particular: `This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.`

The method `async Task Call_A_ToTemp()` never awaits the call to grain B. Instead, it returns immediately after issuing the call. Because the `Task` returned by `Call_A_ToTemp()` is immediately completed, another call is allowed to execute on the grain. Once `grain.CallA()` completes, the continuation (`ContinueWith(...)`) will execute on the grain's `TaskScheduler` as soon as possible (eg, while the grain is awaiting another call or sitting idle).

Instead, if the call was awaited or if `async` was removed from the method and the code changed to return the `grain.CallA().ContinueWith(...)` call then the expected behavior will be observed. I.e, changing the code to this will give you the expected result:

```
// removed 'async' here, since we're not awaiting anything.
// using 'async' is preferred, but this is to demonstrate a point about
// using ContinueWith and un-awaited calls
public Task Call_A_ToTemp()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Making call A to a fellow grain");
   IGrainB grain = this.GrainFactory.GetGrain<IGrainB>(1);

   // Note the 'return' here
   return grain.CallA().ContinueWith((t)=>
   {
     if(t.IsFaulted)
     {
       // Silo message timeout is 32s so t.IsFaulted is true
       Console.WriteLine("Task Faulted");
       Call_A_ToTemp();
     }
    });
}
```

Comment: `continuation (ContinueWith(...)) will execute on the grain's TaskScheduler as soon as possible ` What does `as soon as possible` mean? After the current task ends on the scheduler?

Comment: Precisely. Each activation has a custom TaskScheduler which is responsible for executing tasks one-by-one. So when the `ContinueWith(...)` is ready to run, its continuation `Task` will be enqueued on the scheduler and executed.

Comment: I was doing some more experiments and had another related question. Can you please look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54513019/interleaving-of-orleans-tasks ?