# Interleaving of Orleans tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net, actor, orleans

There is a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54456369/orleans-single-threaded-nature-not-respected-by-continuewith) where Orleans task execution in context of `ContinueWith` is discussed. I modified the example a bit more to check if two tasks of the same grain in Orleans can be made to interleave without the [Reentrant] flag. The entire code is [here](https://github.com/avinash0161/OrleansExperiments/tree/interleave-test). The highlights of the code are as follows:

```
// Client code
var hashGenerator = client.GetGrain<IHashGeneratorGrain>(0);
Console.WriteLine("Client making a call");
hashGenerator.Call_A_ToTemp();
await Task.Delay(10000);
hashGenerator.Call_B_ToTemp();


// HashGeneratorGrain
public async Task Call_A_ToTemp()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Making call A to a fellow grain");
    ITempGrain grain = this.GrainFactory.GetGrain<ITempGrain>(1);

    // CallA() returns successfully in 20s that is less than the timeout.
    grain.CallA().ContinueWith(async (t)=> 
    {
       if (t.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
       {
          Console.WriteLine("Task success");
          Console.WriteLine("Call_A_ToTemp: Counter value now is: " + counter);
          var selfGrain = this.GrainFactory.GetGrain<IHashGeneratorGrain>(0);
          await selfGrain.IncCounter();
          Console.WriteLine("Call_A_ToTemp: after increment: " + this.counter);
       }
    }
    );
}

public async Task IncCounter() 
{
   this.counter += 1;
}

public async Task Call_B_ToTemp()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Call_B_ToTemp called");
   Console.WriteLine("Call_B_ToTemp: Counter value now is: " + counter);
   Console.WriteLine("Call_B_ToTemp: now sleep for 20s");
   await Task.Delay(20000);
   Console.WriteLine("Call_B_ToTemp: after sleep value: " + counter);
   this.counter += 1;
   Console.WriteLine("Call_B_ToTemp: after increment: " + this.counter);
}

// TempGrain
public async Task CallA()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Call A came to TempGrain");
    await Task.Delay(20000);
}
```

The output of this was:

```
Client making a call
Making call A to a fellow grain
Call A came to TempGrain
Call_B_ToTemp called
Call_B_ToTemp: Counter value now is: 0
Call_B_ToTemp: now sleep for 20s
Task success
Call_A_ToTemp: Counter value now is: 0
Call_A_ToTemp: after increment: 1
Call_B_ToTemp: after sleep value: 1
Call_B_ToTemp: after increment: 2
```

As we can see, `Call_B_ToTemp()` didn't complete, but `IncCounter()` was called in between and after it exited, `Call_B_ToTemp()` executed and finished.

Doesn't this violate the single threadedness of Orleans grains?

Comment: I am curious, you have asked a couple of questions and you don't seem to trust the implementation of Orleans, why do you consider using it then when you are not trusting its single-threaded (per grain) execution? I think you have problems understanding Task and async/await. As Reuben told you, the behavior you see, is because you do not await `grain.CallA().ContinueWith(async (t)=>` line, neither you do return its task. You are doing a fire & forget action here. What happens is: CallA() is called with continuation.

Comment: Since its not awaited or its task returned, the grain call is **COMPLETED** from Orleans point of view (`Call_A_ToTemp()`'s task is completed). This signals Orleans, that the execution is done and a next message can be processed. When you call `Call_B_ToTemp()`, the message is started and processed and then **awaited**. During the time you await within `Call_B_ToTemp()`, the `ContinueWith` is called and executed.

Comment: At any given time the Grain is only accessed by a single thread. But the kind of interleaving you see is because you don't await. `Task` doesn't mean a new thread. Just await (or return) in `grain.CallA().ContinueWith(async (t)=> ` and you will see the desired behavior

Comment: This is all about async, there are never 2 threads involved at the same time. When you await, the thread is returned to the orleans pool. This is different if you would use `Thread.Sleep`, because then the thread would be blocked.However,single-threaded nature doesn't mean that there is one (physical) thread per grain,it just says that a grains method can only be processed by a single message (method call)  at the same time which behaves like a single-threaded application, but isn't really only running on a single thread (the methods can be called by Thread 1, 4, 20, just not at the same time)

Comment: The single threaded guarantees are there obviously only for the **public calls** (defined in the grain interface), because these ones are called from the Orleans task scheduler afaik. When you **don't await or return a task** as in your case, you see this behavior

Comment: iirc orleans task scheulder internally has a thread pool of something like number of pyhsical cores * 2 threads, so on a 4-core machine that's 8 threads, even if there are 10000 active grains which are used to run grain methods. And you shouldn't do long running cpu work inside your grains (since that blocks orleans managed threads) and instead have fast actions and use `Task.Run` when you have computation heavy (or synchronous-blocking) tasks (this returns the orlean task to the pool and starts the work on a default thread pool thread), so it doesn't reduce your throughput to heavily.

Comment: @Tseng... It's not a question about trust. There is a difference between trusting and understanding. And you are spot on in saying that I haven't understood this topic correctly.

Comment: I understood that the reason `ContinueWith()` interleaves with `Call_B_ToTemp()`  is because I don't call await. But this question is about why `IncCounter()` interleaves with `Call_B_ToTemp()`. Afaik, the task scheduler should treat `IncCounter()` as any other message arriving at the grain and it shouldn't let it interleave with any other message. Why does the fact that it originated inside the `ContinueWith` affect its behavior? For the task scheduler, `IncCounter()` is a message same as any other message. Any reading sources/documentation about this will be greatly appreciated.